# Is there a better way to write this in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class Palindrome
{
   public static void main ( String [] args )
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in ) ; // new object named "scan"
       System.out.println ( "\nPlease enter a number: "  ) ;
       int num = scan.nextInt () ; //store number into num

       if ( ( (num /1000)==(num%10) ) 
            && (    ( (num/10) %10 ) == ( (num/100)%10  )   ) ) 
           // num = 'abcd' : if (a=d) and (b=c) number is a palindrome.
            System.out.println ( "\nIs a Palindrome !"  ) ;
      else 
            System.out.println ( "\nNot a Palindrome !"  ) ;
   } //end of method main
} //end of class Palindrome
```

1. Is there a way to optimize this code?
   I need to deal only with a 4 digits number ONLY !
2. How do I add a check that the number is a truly a positive number and a 4 digits number ?

Comment: You don’t know how to check if an `int` is a positive number?

Comment: Thanks for the exercise. But.. what have you tried? What are your first guesses, what specific help can we offer? SO is not a "Do my homework" site.

Comment: You could also convert your number to a `String` and perform your palindrome check on the characters. (Or, leave the input from the user as a `String` in the first place.)

Comment: what's with the horrendous usage of magic numbers? just check the reverse of the string is the same as the original...

Comment: You can get rid of all the extra modulus operations

Comment: Reversing a String sounds like a form of cheating. Staying numeric looks much more elegant to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I add a check that the number is a truly: first, a positive number, and second, a 4 digits number?

I could interpret 4-digit non-negative integer two ways.

```
0 <= n && n <= 9999
```

or

```
1000 <= n && n <= 9999
```

To optimize, I wouldn't bother parsing it from a String:

```
BufferedReader bufferedInput = new BufferedReader(System.in);
String line = bufferedInput.readLine();
if (line == null) { /* handle end of input case */ }
String number = line.trim();
// Check if its a palindrome
if (number.length() == 4
    && number.charAt(0) == number.charAt(3)
    && number.charAt(1) == number.charAt(2)) {
  // Finally check that the characters are all digits
  boolean isLegal = true;
  for (int i = (number.length() + 1) / 2; --i >= 0;) {
    char shouldBeADigit = number.charAt(i);
    if (!('0' <= shouldBeADigit && shouldBeADigit <= '9')) {
      isLegal = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isLegal) {
    System.out.println(number + " is a palindrome");
  }
}
```

Comment: If you do the palindrome check first, then you need only check the first n/2 characters (n/2 + 1 if length is odd) since by the definition of a palindrome the others must be digits as well.

Comment: It is not ok to check only 1000 <= num && num <= 9999, because if the user types: 1200.89 what will happened now ?

Comment: @Mosh you are using `int`  you want to use `double`

Comment: @M. Jessup, quite right, but if its length is odd, I think you only need to check (n/2 - 1) since the middle one is always equal to itself.

Comment: @Mike, you still need to check the middle, since you are checking if it is a digit. i.e. if you're palindrome test is true (assuming it is agnostic to number letters) and you don't check the middle the string "123Z321" would be considered valid. (This is all predicated on the palindrome test not verfiying a number). However to only check palindrome I agree n/2 is sufficient (I think you had a typo with n/2 -1 e.g. n=7, n/2=3 with integer division, the fourth character is irrelevant). This is what I did in my sample solution below (though it may not be horribly obvious it only checks n/2).

Answer (score 3):

Split the task into smaller, more manageable pieces, that you can solve. For example:

To check if string has length 4:

```
static boolean is4Digit(String p) {  
  return p.length()==4; 
}
```

To check if number is between 2 numbers:

```
static boolean isBetween(int nr, int low, int hi) {  
  return nr>low && nr<hi; 
}
```

To check if string is a palindrome:

```
static boolean isPalindrome(String p) {  
  return p.equals(new StringBuilder(p).reverse().toString());  
}
```

Comment: System.out.println is not in the Scanner class

Answer (score 0):

A more readable way would be this:

```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in ) ; // new object named "scan"
   System.out.println ( "\nPlease enter a number: "  ) ;
   int num = scan.nextInt () ; //store number into num

   if(num<0 || num>9999)
       System.out.println("Only positive numbers with 4 digits are accepted.");
   else {
       int help=num;
       int rev=0;

       while (help > 0) {
           rev = rev * 10 + help %10;
           help = help / 10;
       }
       System.out.println("Is a palindrome: "+ (rev==num));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check where the input is a number

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
  NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
  ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
  formatter.parse(str, pos);
  return str.length() == pos.getIndex();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A purely mathematical implementation of isPalindrome (no string conversion) that is somewhat more efficient than Chris' (though certainly even less intuitive / readable):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
  if(number < 0){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("number must be positive!");
  }
  int powerOf10 = (int)Math.pow(10, (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(number)));
  while(powerOf10 >= 10) {
    number -= powerOf10 * (number % 10);
    if(number < 0 || number >= powerOf10) {
      return false;
    }
    number /= 10;
    powerOf10 /= 100;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Since this is a homework question I will leave the explanation of why this works as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using a regex with capture groups and back references.  Consider this regular expression to capture two digits and then capture two more digits that are equal to the first two in reverse order:

```
 private static String PALINDROME = "(\\d)(\\d)(?:\\2)(?:\\1)";

 public boolean isPalindrome(String testStr) throws NoMatchFoundException {
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PALINDROME);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
     return matcher.matches(); 
 }
```